# Set single item scroll on mousewheel and multiple item scroll on button click in owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel, mousewheel

Currently, It scrolls 3 items on both next-previous button click and on mouse scroll.

My setting is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
          owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            margin: 10,
            slideBy: 'page',
            dots: false,
            responsive: {
              0: {
                items: 1
              },
              600: {
                items: 3
              },
              960: {
                items: 5
              },
              1200: {
                items: 3
              }
            }
          });
          owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function(e) {
            if (e.deltaY < 0) {
                owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
            } else {
                owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
          });
        });
```

Basically, it scrolls 3 items because of my setting `slideBy: 'page'`. But, I want single item scroll on mousescroll.

Only a hint will be fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Dharmesh

1. You can use `owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [0, 500]);` to replace `owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');` `owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');`
2. Custom owl.carousel.js. find `Navigation.prototype.getPosition` `Navigation.prototype.next` `Navigation.prototype.prev` method and custom the
   params;

This is my custom demo page:
https://gyx8899.github.io/YX-JS-ToolKit/pages/owlCarousel2/owl-mousewheel.html

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. but, seriously I don't understand anything. so, can you please describe in brief?

Comment: It trigger the same api when you click and mousewheel.
#1, you can use ‘to.owl.carousel’ when you can get the first active item index. "owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [index, 500]);" (I could not get this, you can have a try)
#2, you can custom owl.carousel.js as which I have.